# Access files in other domain

Tags: php, apache, file, cpanel, whm

Very easy, I have:

`domain1.com`
`domain2.com`

Set on a **cPanel/WHM dedicated server**

I want to access an image from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com` but without using the full http route

Instead of this

`<img src="http://www.domain1.com/files/image1.jpg" />`

I want to do this:

`<img src="../../domain1/public_html/files/image1.jpg" />`

**How do I do this?**

Answer (score 1):

It can be done... but only if both domains are on the same server.

On a Linux/BSD (or any *nix) server you could set create a symbolic link in your domain2 www directory to the actual directory in domain1.

If you use Apache, you might be able to redirect requests transparently using .htaccess. but this is a bit more difficult to do and may not work on all Apache installations.

With both these solutions you'll end up with URL's that make domain1 look like a subdirectory of domain2. For example:

```
<img src="/domain1/files/image1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The image's `src` attribute requires the **public** HTTP address, not the physical file location on disk.

Comment: So I can't do it that way? I don't want to leave any REFERER trail to the domain1 statistics and I'm afraid doing it that way definetely will.

Comment: No you can't do it this way. You are trying to hack the internet in a way it is not intended. Maybe re-think the architecture of your application, rather than trying to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This Can't be done. You have to give the http path for image source. The file location address  in the image source like document  `/path/to/file/in/the/system`  will never work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do unless you configure a virtualhost with Apache that *just* leads to that image directory. As Greg said, the  tag required a public url.

Comment: how would I configure a virtualhost?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Symbolic Link to files directory.

```
ln -s path-to-actual-folder name-of-link
```

to confirm, do:

```
ls -ld name-of-link
```